# Can a retired non-EU citizen (resident in Ireland) move to The Netherlands and still have healthcare/social rights?

Tags: netherlands, relocation, ireland, health-care

I am an American retiree living in Ireland. After living here for 5 years, I will be getting a long-term resident permit. At that point would I be able move permanently to another EU country (The Netherlands) with social benefits such as healthcare?
Thank you,
Sue Whalon

Comment: Once you've received your long-term resident permit from Ireland, you **will** be an EU resident. (Not an EU citizen, but an EU resident.) The title to your question is thus inconsistent with the question's text. I have amended the title to conform to the question. If you disagree with my amendment, you can "undo" or "revert" the title to your original text, using the "edit" button below the question text.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica someone who resides in Ireland with a residence permit that isn't a long-term residence permit is still a resident of an EU country.  Perhaps the better edit would have been to add "citizen" (...retired non-EU citizen resident in Ireland...).  In any event, the EU has a directive providing for acquisition of "long-term resident" status after 5 years, which carries with it the possibility of moving to another EU country more easily, but Ireland opted out of that directive, so the Netherlands would not have to offer this facility to long-term residents of Ireland.

Comment: @phoog I agree that your locution is more accurate, thanks. I have again amended the title.

Answer (score -1):

No. Unless you are a EU citizen you can't claim benefits or pensions in Ireland.

Your immigration status is given if you are not burden for the state.